# AMAZON RDS(aurora) snapshots backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Hi I am using amazon aurora as database for my project.
I am using auto backup option to backup my databases.
RDS services is providing backups only for 35 days(max backup days).
My requirement is I want to backup my databases for an year continuously instead of 35 days I mean I want to have database backups of whole year with me. or is it possible to move db snapshots to s3 to save for longer period of time.
Is there anyway to achieve this
another question is,
Is there anyway I can backup only sql dumps instead of db snapshots.

It would be great if anyone answer my question
Thanks in advance
Satheesh

Answer (score 2):

You can copy automated snapshots to create manual DB snapshots in S3 for point in time recovery. Here is link guiding the same :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html

Apart from that the other way to keep backup is to keep an external db dump via any sql tool.

Answer (score 0):

Manual backups on aurora database does not have expiration. My advice is to take a manual backup, move it to s3 and set a retention policy which will move that to glacier if you do not need it right away. Restoring from glacier takes longer tho but its cost effective for snapshots that you do not need right away.